# Fourier transform inverse fourier transform python

Tags: python, opencv, signal-processing, fft

I've deconstructed a picture of a dog into its magnitude and phase components. However when I put them back together and try to do the inverse fourier transform I do not get the original image?

```
img1 = img1[:,:,2] 

plt.imshow(img1, cmap='gray')

plt.show()

dft = cv2.dft(np.float32(img1), flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)

print(dft)

dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)

print(dft_shift)

mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(dft_shift[:,:,0],dft_shift[:,:,1])

plt.imshow(20*np.log(mag), cmap='gray')

plt.show()

plt.imshow(ang, cmap='gray')

plt.show()

combined = np.multiply(mag, np.exp(1j*ang))

imgCombined = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(combined)))

plt.imshow(imgCombined, cmap='gray')

plt.show()
```

fixed!

```
def compute_mag_phase(toBeTransfromed):
    dft = np.fft.fft2(toBeTransfromed)
    dft_shift = np.fft.fftshift(dft)
    mag = np.abs(dft_shift)
    ang = np.angle(dft_shift)
    return mag, ang

def reconstruct(mag,ang):
    combined = np.multiply(mag, np.exp(1j*ang))
    fftx = np.fft.ifftshift(combined)
    ffty = np.fft.ifft2(fftx)
    imgCombined = np.abs(ffty)
    return imgCombined
```

Magnitude:

[image: magnitude]

Angle:

[image: angle]

Reconstructed:

[image: reconstructed]

Comment: try idft 
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#gaa708aa2d2e57a508f968eb0f69aa5ff1

Comment: I do not see that you did your dft_scale as mentioned in the docs link from   Birol Kuyumcu. It would also be helpful if you posted your input dog image so others can test your code and show your code for reading your image. See this forums help section about providing minimally reproducible and verifiable code.

Answer (score 0):

`fftshift` inverted your third dimension of `dft_shift`.
The following seems to work

```
dft_real = np.fft.fftshift(dft[:, :, 0])
dft_imag = np.fft.fftshift(dft[:, :, 1])
mag, ang = cv2.cartToPolar(dft_real, dft_imag)
```

Comment: @Jamie Thompson, please to let me know if this didn't help...

Comment: sorry for the late reply, it appears it does. I stopped using carToPolar in the end: